# Uploading an empty file automatically results in an NPE

Tags: java, file-upload, nullpointerexception, playframework

I'm a bit of a newbie to the Play Framework, but I don't see any documentation on how to approach this.  Basically I've got a form to upload a text file to the server, here's the relevant snippet:

```
#{form @Sprockets.upload() , enctype:'multipart/form-data' }
  <input type="file" name="sprocketFile" size="chars" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Sprocket" />
#{/form}
```

On the controller side, here's the upload method:

```
public static void upload(File sprocketFile) {
}
```

My issue is that if the user doesn't bother populating the form and just hits "Submit Sprocket", Play automagically generates an NPE as it tries to convert the form data to a file.  How I can work around this?  This happens even before the controller validation code kicks in, so simply throwing in a @Required doesn't help:

```
@64m30kf1p
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /sprockets/upload

Oops: NullPointerException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception NullPointerException: null

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Errors serializationProblem
    at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.save(ValidationPlugin.java:146)
    at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.onActionInvocationResult(ValidationPlugin.java:65)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:293)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.save(ValidationPlugin.java:136)
    ... 3 more
```

My end goal is to show a pretty error message back to the user, but Play is preventing me from doing this.  This is with Play 1.1 on OS X if it makes a difference.

Comment: Can you provide the whole stacktrace and the exact play-version.

Comment: @niels: Sadly, the above is the full stack trace.

Comment: Crazy I checked the play code and can't see what could be null there :-/ The play-coreteam seems today inactive so be patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the source of the problem, and it's my own fault.  The issue at hand is naturally part of the source I didn't include in the original question.  Here's the sample code:

```
public static void upload(@Required File sprocketFile) {
try {           
  if (sprocketFile == null || validation.hasErrors()) {
    validation.addError("Upload Error", "Please select a sprocket to upload", sprocketFile);
    params.flash();
    validation.keep();                          
    index();
}
```

The issue was using the sprocketFile as the last parameter in validation.addError(). I discovered this while running the app in debug mode in NetBeans.  Thanks for your help @niels.

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround would be an @Before-Interceptor. There you can check the paramter and redirect to an error page. This should work. Please create a ticket at http://play.lighthouseapp.com with a small example application.

Answer (score 0):

You form and controller do not match

```
<input type="file" name="sprocketFile" size="chars" />
```

Says you are uploading a File object to a variable named `sprocketFile`

But, your code says you are storing in an object named `licenceFile`

```
public static void upload(File licenseFile) {
```

Try making the two match.

Comment: Oops, I had changed the variable names to protect the guilty, but didn't catch the one =)  They are consistent in my code, and I've changed them as such above.

Comment: I have never had this problem using files, but I have always used Blob (well, I used FileAttachment prior to Play1.1). Try using Blob instead of File.